# Proxychians for nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have this nginx config file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  10;

    #gzip  on;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name goo.localhost;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;

        location / {
            #resolver 1.1.1.1;
            proxy_pass https://google.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Origin google.com;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            sub_filter "https://google.com" "";
        }
    }
}
```

I want make reverse proxy then load google.com on my localhost ( this a example! ) but google.com is block in my network I need use proxy server to load google.com!
I setup a proxychains with this config:

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 3.1

random_chain

proxy_dns 

tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

[ProxyList]

http 123.123.123.123 8080 qwe test
```

and run: `proxychains nginx -g 'daemon off;'`

but I get this error for every request: `[error] 8#8: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: goo.localhost, request: "GET /x/x HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://x.x.x.x:x/x/x", host: "localhost"`

Note1: If my network not block google.com, reverse proxy works!
Note2: http proxy server works!

proxychains curl https://google.com is ok!